# How jvm determines to perform the coustmized sorting in treeset?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, treeset

How JVM determines to perform the customized sorting,when an object is passed as an argument to tree-set Constructor which in turn implements Comparator interface.

```
package sorting;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Comparator;

class CoustmizedSorting implements Comparator<Integer>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
        if(arg0>arg1)
            return -1;
        else if(arg0<arg1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
public class SimpleSort{
    private static Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> tree=new TreeSet<>(new CoustmizedSorting());
        System.out.println("enter the numbers");
        tree.add(scan.nextInt());
        tree.add(scan.nextInt());
        tree.add(scan.nextInt());
        tree.add(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(tree);
    }
}
```

As i understood ,their is a compareTo method which in-turn performs the procedure to sort out the elements.My question is ....

> what happens when new object**[Set tree=new TreeSet<>(new
>   CoustmizedSorting());]**

is passed as an argument to the tree-set Constructor and how it manages to call compareTo() method to sort out the elements?

Am not new to java but,i quite couldn't understand the concept of passing the new object which in-turn manages to call or sort-out the elements.

Comment: Treeset internally uses TreeMap and put method is implemented as mentioned here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `TreeSet` is backed by a `TreeMap` (Which is *ultimately* a `SortedMap`).

Whenever you pass a *Comparator* to the `TreeSet`, it is passed on to the supporting `TreeMap`. The Treemap has the following code in its put :

```
public V put(K key, V Value){
// some code

 Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
        if (cpr != null) {
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
        else {
            if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }

//some code
}
```

Comment: Whenever you pass a Comparator to the TreeSet?dose it mean,class implementing the Comparator interface.

Comment: @Terminator - Yes. You are passing an *instance* of the class implementing the *Comparator* interface.

Comment: thanks for the valuable answer.Just for the confirmation can we use the Comparator interface on List objects or any other objects which in-turn use collection.

Comment: @Terminator - Yes.You can pass *Comparator* to `Arrays.sort()` and `Collections.sort()`